# How is Azure Frontdoor Origin type defined in Bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep, azure-front-door

On the portal we can configure the Origin type as for example Storage (blobs) or Storage (static web site). I don't see such a property in a bicep script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a value for the "origin type" in the ARM template.  I believe the Azure Portal uses this "Origin type" drop down to determine which existing resources to reference for the origin.  Selecting an existing resource populates the "Origin hostname" in the portal, which populates the "hostName" property in the ARM template.

In the bicep file you'll populate the "hostName" property and there is no need to worry about the "Origin type" exposed in the Azure Portal;  it's only there for the portal.